# Display back button in ion-nav-bar iOS only

Tags: ionic-framework

Though I'm sure this is something that isn't uncommon in ionic development, I can't seem to find anything on the web that explains this. If I have the following:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

</body>
```

And one of the views that I use in the `ion-nav-view` looks like this for exmaple:

```
<ion-view view-title="Profile" ng-controller="profileController" class="profile-view">
  <ion-content class="padding has-header">
  ....
```

How do I display a back button (really just the `ion-chevron-left` icon) for iOS only, and have it hidden on other devices that have a dedicated hardware button?

Comment: Alternatively the back button is just going to have to show on Android. That's what you get for having 15 different ways to do one thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve platform specific behaviour. You can read up on the back button specifically, [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavBackButton/).

1. In your controller, you can use the [ionic.Platform](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/) utility to determine the current platform and the Ionic [NavBarDelegate](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicNavBarDelegate/) to show/hide the button.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-bar-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>
</body>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $ionicNavBarDelegate) {
   var isIOS = ionic.Platform.isIOS();
   $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBackButton(isIOS);
});
```

2. In your css, define separate classes to show/hide the element depending on the platform. From [here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-use-platform-ios-and-platform-cordova-css-classes/5898).

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button class="platform-nav"></ion-nav-bar-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.platform-ios .platform-nav {
    display: block;
}
.platform-android .platform-nav {
    display: none;
}
```